# Compile C# library projects requiring bindingRedirect

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am referencing a third party dll that requires a bindingRedirect in the app.config file as follows:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I am trying to reference this in a C# library project. The library will be shared between a WCF project and MVC project. 
However the my library cannot find the references anymore. I get the following warning:

> The primary reference "ThirdParty" could not be resolved because it
>   has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "ThirdParty" or retarget your application to a framework
>   version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

I have added an app.config file to the library with the required bindingRedirect. However this configuration is ignored.

I have also tried converting the library to a console application. In this case it compiles perfectly and works.

How does one compile a library project that requires assemblyBinding to do a bindingRedirect?

Comment: As the tag `runtime` indicates, assembly binding only works for runtime binding. At compile time you need to provide the correct references, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In spite of the correct references, the library no longer compiles. The error says `The type or namespace name 'ThirdParty' does not exist`. In the project warnings, there is the above warning saying `The primary reference "ThirdParty" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a compile-time error because the third party DLL exposes types from System.Net.Http.  You simply need to add the reference to the System.Net.Http assembly to resolve it.

Do so by using Nuget.  You want the [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http).

Comment: That is simply not true. My project stopped compiling after removing bindingredirect

Comment: Well, clearly it was true for the OP.  Use the Ask Question button to get help with your particular issue, be sure to describe it well.