# Conflict of version for NLog

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, nlog, assembly-binding-redirect

I am trying to compile my project named `MyAssembly`, and when including other assembly named `ExternalAssembly` that also references NLog, I get the following error :

```
Assembly ExternalAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0 uses NLog, Version=2.1.0.0 which has a higher version than referenced assembly NLog, Version=2.0.0.0
```

I went to my app config and added the following entry:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120E14C03D0593C" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>      
        ...
```

But I still get the same error.

Any ideas about why it is not working, and how to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried changing `oldVersion` to `0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0`?

Comment: Are you referencing any libraries that also have a dependency on NLog?

Comment: try to switch the oldVersion and newVersion values.

Comment: I tried to switch the old version and new version values, adding `0.0.0.0-` prefix to oldversion, I still get exactly the same error.

Comment: @Hammerstein yes, the assembly `ExternalAssembly`, I changed my answer to include it.

Comment: So, this is a compile time error. Binding redirects work only during runtime. See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404015/compile-c-sharp-library-projects-requiring-bindingredirect

Comment: Yes it is a compile time error, so what is the trick to solve this problem?

Comment: You will have to add reference to the nlog version 2.1.0.0 for compiling.

Comment: There is no way of avoiding updating the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to upgrade the NLog reference of my project to match the one of the third party (2.1.0.0).