# Is it possible to ignore a compile-time assembly version mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am encountering the error

> Assembly 'A' uses 'B, Version 2.0.0.0' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'B, 1.0.0.0'

I am aware of what this error means, and that the usual solution would be to upgrade the referenced assembly so that the versions match. What I am wondering is whether it is possible to force the use of the older version (and have the application fail at runtime if there are any differences in the parts of the assembly that are being used).

According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404015/compile-c-sharp-library-projects-requiring-bindingredirect) question, [binding redirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) work only at runtime. Is there a similar mechanism to redirect at compile-time?

(I am aware that this is a horrible idea, the question is **mostly** academic)

Comment: You could set the `Specific Version` property of your assembly reference to `False`, so Visual Studio will not check the versions at compile time. You'll get into trouble at run-time though, if interfaces change in the referenced assemblies between the versions.

Comment: I tried that out just now, but it didn't remove the compiler error. I think that property only works when comparing the referenced version to a physical assembly version, not when comparing two referenced versions.